# Using variables through scripts using module.exports not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

So im pulling my hair here and everything I've tried hasn't worked. I have a simple node.js app structure, like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var mysql = require('mysql');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


//Database handler
//Here is completed with the data
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  database: ""
});

con.connect(function (err) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("connected");
});

app.listen(55132, function () {
  console.log("Server running at port 55132");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Quite simple, some routing but nothing weird. I need to use the variable con in my other scripts, so i've tried this:

```
module.exports.database = con;
```

So i should be able to use it in my index.js script (see `var indexRouter`), soooo here is the index.js script:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let app = require('../app');

let connection = app.database;

console.log(app); //Here returns {} so I can´t access any of the properties of the module

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

}

module.exports = router;
```

I don't know what should I do, some suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for forther reading i recommend you to read this 
>   https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut

just change you app file export to

```
 module.exports = {app,con};
```

and in your index file

```
const {app,con} = require('./app');
let connection = con;
```

Comment: just edit my answer .did you use it the same as me? if not please post your new code

Comment: Its exactly the same as shown at the post but with the modifications you've suggested :/

Comment: ok so please console log app and con inside index.js and upload the output

Comment: Finally got it working, for some reason the Express library routing was creating conflict, i've used another file for testing it and now it's working, marking as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can you try with

for and example :

```
var function = function(coid, userid, callback)   {}
exports.function = function ;
```

in your case

```
exports.database = con;
```

Now it should work, you won't need to add module in the above.